# Six subplots with the same number of xticklabels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, label, subplot

I am really struggling with matplotlib, escpecially with the axis settings. My goal is to set up 6 subplots in one figure, which all display different datasets but have the same amount of ticklabels.

The relevant part of my sourcecode looks like:

**graph4.py:**

```
# Import Matolotlib Modules #
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib import ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif']='Arial' #set font to arial 

# Import GTK Modules #

import gtk

#Import System Modules #
import sys

# Import Numpy Modules #
from numpy import genfromtxt
import numpy

# Import Own Modules #
import mysubplot as mysp

class graph4():
    weekdays = ['Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag']

    def __init__(self, graphview):
        #create new Figure
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(100,100), dpi=75)

        #create six subplots within self.figure
        self.subplot = []
        for j in range(6):
            self.subplot.append(self.figure.add_subplot(321 + j))


        self.__conf_subplots__() #configure title, xlabel, ylabel and grid of all subplots  


        #to make it look better    
        self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.125, bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.96, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.6)    

        #Matplotlib <-> GTK
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure) # a gtk.DrawingArea 
        self.canvas.set_flags(gtk.HAS_FOCUS|gtk.CAN_FOCUS)
        self.canvas.grab_focus()
        self.canvas.show()
        graphview.pack_start(self.canvas, True, True)


        #add labels and grid to all subplots  
        def __conf_subplots__(self):
            index = 0
            for i in self.subplot: 
                mysp.conf_subplot(i, 'Zeit', 'Menge', graph4.weekdays[index], True)
                i.plot([], [], 'bo') #empty plot
                index +=1


        def plot(self, filename_list):
            index = 0
            for filename in filename_list:
                data = genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',') #load data from filename
                if data.size != 0: #only if file isn't empty
                    if index <= len(self.subplot): #plot every file on a different subplot
                        mysp.plot(self.subplot[index],data[0:, 1], data[0:, 0])
                        index +=1


            self.canvas.draw()


            def clear_plot(self):
                #clear axis of all subplots 
                for i in self.subplot:
                    i.cla()

                self.__conf_subplots__()
```

**mysubplot.py: (helper module)**

```
# Import Matplotlib Modules
from matplotlib.axes import Subplot 
import matplotlib.dates as md
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import Own Modules #
import mytime as myt

# Import Numpy Modules #
import numpy as np

def conf_subplot(subplot, xlabel, ylabel, title, grid):
    if(xlabel != None):
        subplot.set_xlabel(xlabel) 
    if(ylabel != None):
        subplot.set_ylabel(ylabel) 
    if(title != None):
        subplot.set_title(title) 
    subplot.grid(grid)

    #rotate xaxis labels 
    plt.setp(subplot.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30, fontsize=12)

    #display date on xaxis
    subplot.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))      
    subplot.xaxis_date()


def plot(subplot, x, y):
    subplot.plot(x, y, 'bo')
```

I think the best way to explain what goes wrong is with the use of screenshots. After I start my application, everything looks good:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SqwaPyG.png]

If I double click a 'Week'-entry on the left, the method `clear_plot()` in **graph4.py** is called to reset all subplots. Then a list of filenames is passed to the method `plot()` in **graph4.py**. The method `plot()` opens each file and plots each dataset on a different subplot. So after I double click a entry, it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, each subplot has a different number of xtick labels, which looks pretty ugly to me. Therefore, I am looking for a solution to improve this. My first approach was to set the ticklabels manually with `xaxis.set_ticklabels()`, so that each subplot has the same number of ticklabels. However, as strange as it sounds, this only works on some datasets and I really don't know why. On some datasets, everything works fine and on other datasets, matplotlib is basically doing what it wants and displays xaxis labels that I didn't specify. I also tried `FixedLocator()`, but I got the same result. On some datasets it is working and on others, matplotlib is using a different number of xtick labels.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

As @sgpc suggested, I tried to use pyplot. My sourcecode now looks like this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.dates as md

mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif']='Arial' #set font to arial 

import gtk
import sys

# Import Numpy Modules #
from numpy import genfromtxt
import numpy

# Import Own Modules #
import mysubplot as mysp

class graph2():
    weekdays = ['Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag']

    def __init__(self, graphview):
        self.figure, temp = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=3, sharex = True)

        #2d array -> list
        self.axes = [ y for x in temp for y in x]

        #axis: date
        for i in self.axes:
            i.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
            i.xaxis_date()  

        #make space and rotate xtick labels
        self.figure.autofmt_xdate() 

        #Matplotlib <-> GTK
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure) # a gtk.DrawingArea 
        self.canvas.set_flags(gtk.HAS_FOCUS|gtk.CAN_FOCUS)
        self.canvas.grab_focus()
        self.canvas.show()
        graphview.pack_start(self.canvas, True, True)

    def plot(self, filename_list):
        index = 0
        for filename in filename_list:
            data = genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',') #get dataset
            if data.size != 0: #only if file isn't empty
                if index < len(self.axes): #print each dataset on a different subplot 
                    self.axes[index].plot(data[0:, 1], data[0:, 0], 'bo')
                    index +=1

        self.canvas.draw()

    #not yet implemented
    def clear_plot(self):
        pass
```

If I plot some datasets, I get the following output: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w1r2.png (sorry, I still don't have enough reputation to embedd pictures)

Moreover, I am not really sure if sharing the x-axis is a really good idea, because it is possible that the x-values differ in every subplot (for example: in the first subplot, the x-values ranges from 8:00am - 11:00am and in the second subplot the x-values ranges from 7:00pm - 9:00pm).

If I get rid of `sharex = True`, I get the following output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDHeA.png (sorry, I still don't have enough reputation to embedd pictures)

As you can see, the output now looks better. However now, the labels on the x-axes are not updated. I assume that is because the last suplots are empty.

My next attempt was to use an axis for each subplot. Therefore, I made this changes:

```
for i in self.axes:
    plt.setp(i.get_xticklabels(), visible=True, rotation = 30) #<-- I added this line...
    i.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
    i.xaxis_date() 

#self.figure.autofmt_xdate() #<--changed this line
self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.125, bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.96, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.6) #<-- and added this line
```

Now I get the following output:

i.imgur.com/TmA1goE.png (sorry, I still don't have enough reputation to embedd pictures)

So with this attempt, I am basically struggling with the same problem as with `Figure()` and `add_subplot()`.

I really don't know, what else I could try to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you to use `pyplot.subplots()` with `sharex=True`:

```
fig, axes = subplots(ncols=2, nrows=3, sharex= True)
```

Then you access each axes using:

```
ax = axes[i,j]
```

And you can plot doing:

```
ax.plot(...)
```

To control the number of ticks for each `AxesSubplot` you can use:

```
ax.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=6)
```

OBS: `axis` can be `'x'`, `'y'` or `'both'`

Comment: nordev: Thanks for adding the pictures!

@sgpc: Thanks, I will give it a try. I used Figure() together with add_subplot() in the first place, because I thought that it isn't possible to embedd a pyplot plot in a GTK window. At least, I thought, that I read it somewhere in the matplotlib documentation. However, I am not really sure about this now... I will give it a try!

Comment: ok, just let me know if you need some help... I use `subplots` a lot and it works pretty well...

Comment: I tried pyplot, but came across some problems (see my edit in the first post). Do you have an idea what else I could try to make it work?

Comment: @user2494129 could you provide some files in `filename_list`? Maybe in DropBox...

Comment: For sure. I put the files together with a minimalistic demo program in a Dropbox folder and made it public. However, you need some packages (GTK, glade) to make the demo program work. If you are only interested in the datasets, they are in the 'WeekX' folders.
Here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5vt05pivafktr6s/lpNBJp2Cmh

I really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: @user2494129 I took a look to your example and it seems that, from your original question, what you needed is something like: `ax.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=6)` applied for each `AxesSubplot`

Comment: Thanks for reply! `ax.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=6)` only seems to work with `sharex = True`. If I enable the sharex attribute, I get 6 bins, if I however disable sharex, matplotlib uses a different number of bins for each subplot. Another drawback of `ax.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=6)` seems to be, that I cannot use it together with `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))`and `ax.xaxis_date()`. I always get the error: `'AutoDateLocator' object has no attribute 'set_params'`. If I remove those two lines, the error disappears, but now the dates aren't plotted.

Comment: could you try something different... intead of using `subplots`, go back to your previous method, and then try to use `ax.locator_params()`?

Comment: Unfortunately I get the the same error. Right now I am also thinking about alteratives to subplot(s). Principially, I am not tied to subplot(s). If it is possible to plot the data in one graph, it is also fine to me. My main interest goes into the trend of the individual datasets. For example: I want to tell at a glance, if dataset1 has the same trend as all the other datasets. However, sometimes the x-values (the dates) differ greatly from each other. So I am not sure, if it is a good idea to plot it all in one graph. Maybe you know another way how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I looked at `figure.add_axes()`, but I think that too many axes distracts the user more than it really helps, but thanks anyway! I think, I need to think about something else. Maybe the best way is to get rid of all the time information and focus only on the trend of the different datasets...